# How can I store current employment for a user in normalised database form? (I am using PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, erd

I have a `USERS` table and an `EMPLOYMENT` table which links multiple employments to a single user. How can I store the current employment for the user with the constraints that they might not have a current employment, and also they can have only one current employment.

Would a field in the employment table `isCurrent` work as this by default has no constraints on there only being one current employment?

Another preferred alternative I considered is to have a `USER_CURRENT_EMPLOYMENT` table which links a user to an employment, however again what constraints would I require for this to work?

As mentioned I am using postgresql but am more curious as to how this relationship should work regardless of language.

Comment: Do you have information about when a user took and left a job in the `employment` table? If yes, you already have enough information to get the current job.

Comment: Yes so then I would use the end-date as `null` to represent a current employment? This also doesn't solve how to ensure only one record can be set to null at one time?

Comment: Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & relational & non-relational DB design, querying & DBMSs. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask 1 specific question. This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a unique index and the where predicate to enforce uniqueness on user and his/her last day of employment (which is nullable).  This will ensure only one row per user has a NULL value in last_day.

"create unique index idx_current_employer on employment (user_id, (last_day IS NULL)) WHERE last_day IS NULL;"

Here is a complete script to illustrate how to use it:

```
drop table if exists users;
drop table if exists employment;

create table users
(user_id int not null primary key,
user_name varchar(30) not null)
;

create table employment
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
user_id int not null,
employer_id int not null,
last_day date null)
;

--insert joe and his previous 2 employers
insert into users 
values(1,'Joe');

insert into employment (user_id, employer_id, last_day)
values(1,1,'20150831');
insert into employment (user_id, employer_id, last_day)
values(1,2,'20200831');


--unique index
create unique index idx_current_employer on employment (user_id, (last_day IS NULL)) WHERE last_day IS NULL;

--insert Joe's current employer (null last day)
insert into employment (user_id, employer_id, last_day)
values(1,3,null);

--this one fails - can't insert another employer with null last day  
insert into employment (user_id, employer_id, last_day)
values(1,6,null);

--set last day of previous employer first
update employment
set last_day = '20201006'
where user_id = 1
and last_day is null
;

--now insert succeeds
insert into employment (user_id, employer_id, last_day)
values(1,6,null);

--list all employment
select user_id, employer_id, last_day, case when last_day is null then True else False end as is_current 
from employment 
order by 1, 4 desc, 3 desc
;
```